# Nikebetterworld Parallax Effect Demo: image sizes

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

I'm trying to adjust the [Nikebetterworld Parallax Effect Demo](http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/recreate-nikebetterworld-parallax/) to fit my site needs but when I'm changing the images from the ones given in the demo to the ones I need, they seem to overlap in some way and hide each other.
I tried playing with the height properties in the CSS with no luck.
You can see it in action [here](http://froindster.com/demo/)

Any ideas how am I supposed to use different image sizes for each section?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the postition of the second Div to `relative`? 
It seems as if the background for `#second` is starting way higher up the page, perhaps try setting the [background position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) of it:

```
background-position:top;
```

Remember that this pluggin is basically makes the backgrounds of a load of Div's move. The Div's aline top to bottom like a normal webpage but their individual backgrounds move inside, and any subsequent referenced images. With this in mind as long as the background image size exceeds the Div size and is in the right place you should be ok

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment.
I tried changing the div's position to relative or add the background-position:top; attribue to the css but the that didn't change anything.